# making one div the full width of the window minus the width of a floating in div

Tags: css

I have two divs, that floating next to each other

```
<div id="1">div 1</div>
<div id=2"">div 2</div>

#1 {float:left; padding:0 20px; width:200px;}
#2 {float:left; padding-right:20px;}
```

The problem is that the width of div2, automatically sets to the width of the "div 2" text contained within the div. Instead I want that width to be the full width of the window, and when the window is resized to a narrow window, div 2 should resize with it.

I can work out how to do it in javascript, but is there a way to do it in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the the float from #2 and whilst its not exactly how I wanted, it will do the job. It just means that if there is an overflow, it goes below div 1, where as I really wanted it just to remain in the same box.

Answer (score 0):

remove the float property of #2 if it is not necessary for the second div:

```
#2 {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/Gu7kq/1/